# How to compare second page getting correct data from first page or not(Functional testing) in Telerik test studio

Tags: telerik-test-studio

Am testing siliverlight web application.

In my application i have to verify total,price in invoice page with price and total in journal history page.

whether journal history getting correct data from invoice or not i have to test.

Invoice in one page and journal history in other page.how to verify the data.

I have attached invoice image and journal history image please look at that.assist some body how to do that functional test.Please give reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The attachments you referenced do not display with your question, however, I believe the following is what you want to do.

```
1) With recorder navigate to invoice page
2) Enable hover over elements
3) Hover over your element containing the value 'price', click on the blue dot, click on 'Quick Tasks' then select 'Extract - text contains...'
4) Repeat for element containing value for 'total'
5) Databind each variable with a unique name on the test steps page
6) Navigate to your journal History page
7) Hover over the element that contains the value for total, click the blue dot, select 'Build Verification', click content, then click ok
8) Repeat for element containing value for 'total'
9) Go back to test steps click on the verification steps and apply the binding from steps 3 and 4.
```